# What sets does $\mathbb{N}$ include?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, natural-numbers

My text states that the set $\{1, 2, 3...\}$, and the set $\{101, 102, 103, 104...\}$ are elements of $\mathbb{N}$.

Doesn't this imply that $\mathbb{N}=\{1, 2, 3... 101, 102, 103, 104...\{1, 2, 3 \}, \{101, 102, 103, 104\}...\}$ ?

I had presumed that only numbers comprised the set of natural numbers (i.e. the set of natural numbers did not include other sets). Evidently, that's false.

What does $\mathbb{N}$ include, and why must it include what it does?

---- Edited---
I suspect I've misinterpreted the text, so I've inset a clip of it below
[image]
Thank you,

-Hal

Comment: What text is that?

Comment: Those are _subsets_ of $\mathbb N$, not elements of $\mathbb N$

Comment: Your text should say that $\{1,2\}$ is a subset (not an element) of $\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: The sets that you mention are subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and not elements.

Comment: If the text says that, it's incorrect. Both $\{1, 2, \dots\}$ and $\{101, 102, \dots\}$ are subsets of $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, \dots\}$, not elements.

Comment: If your text actually says that the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is an **element** of $\Bbb N$, the author is a total incompetent. What is true is that it is a **subset** of $\Bbb N$, and its **elements** are elements of $\Bbb N$. The same goes for $\{101,102,103,\ldots\}$.

Comment: @DanielR A Transition to Advanced Mathematics

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I've added a screen grab of the text to this question. I suspect that I've misinterpreted it.

Comment: The text should say $S = \mathbb{N}$, not $S \in \mathbb{N}$. It's probably a typo but it's a pretty bad one.

Comment: @jef +1 for Joel's comment. I'll accept if you do.

Answer (score 6):

Copying from my comment, the line

> then $S \in \mathbb{N}$.

should read

> then $S = \mathbb{N}$.

It's clear that this is a typo because the following paragraph states that the only inductive set containing 1 is $\mathbb{N}$, which reiterates that $S = \mathbb{N}$. Unfortunately, this typo is pretty bad because it invalidates the statement of the principle of mathematical induction.